# How to create a push notification that constantly vibrates

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to send a push notification to an iOS device that constantly buzzes/makes a noise until they swipe to answer it. This is the same as what WhatsApp/Fb Messenger does when you try and video call someone. Is this possible? It looks like whatsapp continuously sends a new push notification and somehow invalidates the old one, but I can't figure that out.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do you solved this problem  ?
i searhed lot of in google but can not find solution
please answer me

Comment: @kirtiChavda This was a long time ago, but I think I just kept sending a notification from the server every X seconds until I received a callback from my app. Using the same ID would remove and replace the old notification. What that ID is exactly, I can't remember but something within the payload

Answer (score 0):

```
   AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

Using the above line will cause the phone to vibrate - if you call this in a timed loop you can get it to vibrate for a certain amount of time.

Continuous vibration however is a common reason for app store rejection see the following -  10base-t.com/unofficial-appstore-rejection-criteria

Comment: It needs to be from a remote notification

Comment: https://q-a-assistant.com/computer-internet-technology/2412938_turn-on-off-vibration-and-sound-while-receiving-remote-notification-ios-swift.html - I'm not very familiar with working with remote notifications - This article could be of use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Calling functionality, please use CallKit and check the below Github libraries,

https://github.com/opentok/CallKit

Comment: I am using it with opentok actually, but I'm video calling. I'm not sure if CallKit would work with video?

Comment: Check this for video calls https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift